# Animation - unexpected position change

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations, center

I have a problem with my code.
I want to make a div rotate, but while div is rotating the position is differend than it was before.

```
.rotateWindow {
   position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  line-height: 32px;
  border: solid 7px;
  border-top: #f8f8ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: #f8f8ff;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: -1;
      -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s; 

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
from {  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
}  
to {  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  
    } 
}
}
```

Without an animation it is in the center of page, after i added the animation it goes under its main position.
Also i tried a simple jquery code and still the same.

```
$(function() {
    var $elie = $('.rotateWindow');
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {

          // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
          // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

          // Animate rotation with a recursive call
        setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },5);
    }
});
```

How can i fix this and why it goes wrong ?
Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `transform-origin: 50% 50%` so your element pivots around its center point.

Comment: Its doing it right now, but not in the place where it should. It should do it in the center of the page, but it doesn't.
Without animation it holds its place in the center, but when i adding the animation it is under the center and a little bit on right

Comment: and transform-origin make no difference